# how to use userdefined functions in drools excel with Drools 5.2.0 version

Tags: drools

Can someone give me an example of how to create a function in drools excel and invoke in the rule condition?

I am using drools `5.2.0` version

I have tried by creating a simple function to return a string value. But not able to invoke the function.

```
testFunction()==$param
```

Getting error as :

> no viable alternative at input ')' in rule "_26" in pattern ConfigRules[97,190]: [ERR 102] Line 97:190 mismatched input '==' expecting ')' in rule "_26" in pattern ConfigRules[122,185]: [ERR 101]

Code snippet:

```
SpreadsheetCompiler sc = new SpreadsheetCompiler(); 
StringBuffer drl = new StringBuffer( sc.compiler(inputStream, InputType.XLS)); 
byte[] drlFileData = drl.toString().getBytes(); 

final KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(); 
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(drlFileDat‌​a), ResourceType.DRL);
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: SpreadsheetCompiler sc = new SpreadsheetCompiler();
StringBuffer drl = new StringBuffer( sc.compiler(inputStream, InputType.XLS));
byte[] drlFileData = drl.toString().getBytes();

Final KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(drlFileData), ResourceType.DRL);

Comment: In the question please.